# pyarrow.hdfs.connect can't reach my hadoop cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, pyarrow

I am struggling with the very first steps in interfacing my functional hadoop installation with python. Here is my main node (local network).

[image]

Here is what's happening when I try to reach my main node:

```
import pyarrow as pa 
pa.hdfs.connect("192.168.0.37",20500)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 181, in connect
kerb_ticket=kerb_ticket, driver=driver)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 35, in __init__
_maybe_set_hadoop_classpath()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 134, in _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath
classpath = subprocess.check_output([hadoop_bin, 'classpath', '--glob'])
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hadoop'
```

I am not sure to understand what I am doing wrong and I found this issue on a lot of different reports. I set my environment variables [according to the documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html) . Here is the end of my .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/david/Apps/hadoop
export CLASSPATH='$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs classpath --glob'
```

It seems like I am getting different errors when running this script directly from my main node. Does it mean that I can't use this script as a client script? Did I miss a step?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `libhdfs` installed?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libhdf4-0  , yep, got it. But it does not seem to change much

Comment: turns out the libhdfs was the issue

Comment: @DavidZarebski Can you provide an actual answer with the solution? I am having the same problem and cannot figure it out. I have libhdfs installed, as far as I can tell (`/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhdfs.so` exists)

Comment: @ KOB to be honest, I forgot. I only had this issue with this specific version of Hadoop so I would suggest to try an other one (I know, it sucks)

Comment: @DavidZarebski I got the same problem! Can you please give more details, how you fixed it?